# Moving trailing week average in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, window-functions, moving-average

My source data includes Transaction ID, Date, Amount. I need a one week trailing average which moves on a daily basis and averaging amount per transaction. Problem is, that sometimes there is no transactions in particuliar date, and I need avg per transaction, no per day, and trailing average moves by day, not by week.In this particular case I can't use OVER with rows preceding.  I'm stack with it :(

Data looks like this:
https://gist.github.com/avitominoz/a252e9f1ab3b1d02aa700252839428dd

Comment: Please edit your question and show the query that you have.  Also, you should put the data structure directly in the question as text, not through an image.

Answer (score 0):

There are two methods to doing this.  One uses `generate_series()` to get all the results.  The second uses a lateral join.

```
with minmax as (
      select min(trade_date) as mintd, max(trade_date) as maxtd
      from sales
     )
select days.dte, s.values,
       avg(values) over (order by days.dte
                         rows between 6 preceding and current row
                        ) as avg_7day
from generate_series(mintd, maxtd, interval '1 day') days(dte) left join
     sales s
     on s.trade_dte = days.dte;
```

Note:  this ignores the values on missing days rather than treating them as `0`.  If you want 0, then use `avg(coalesce(values, 0))`.